# Pausing Outlook Outbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to make Outlook 2003 send an email at a specific time rather than immediately?](https://superuser.com/questions/360010/is-there-a-way-to-make-outlook-2003-send-an-email-at-a-specific-time-rather-than)

I have a program that sends emails to my outlook outbox automatically. Only problem is Outlook sends them before I have time to review them. Anyone know of a way to pause the outbox indefinitely until I authorize a send/recieve - but only for the emails that are pushed in, not all items I send?

Comment: Is it an Exchange, POP3 or IMAP account?

Comment: It is an exchange account

Answer (score 0):

As long as there are no group policies restricting you changing the settings, you can go to `Tools > Options > Mail Setup Tab` then uncheck "Send Immediately when connected".